# аудио библиотеки для php

Tags: php

Всем привет! Кто может подсказать библиотеку для перевода из mp4 во flac на php. Пробовал Sox, но он не поддерживает mp4.

Comment: А в чем смысл переводить lossy в lossless?

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов смысл в том, что звук будет лучше и картинка full-hd 4k+, но нужны позолоченные контакты и hdmi с изоляцией из бивня мамонта

Comment: @Lexx918 так-то да, но в вопросе нет ни слова о деньгах...

Comment: Дело в том, что я использую google speech api, и он не воспринимает mp4

Comment: https://ffmpeg.org/